# Why don't I have "free space" when I have to make partitions to install Ubuntu 18.04 along with Windows 10? I created free space on Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I'm trying to put dual boot on my computer and install Ubuntu along with Windows. I don't have free space when I have to create partitions and also uefi is missing, I can't access boot menu. (I create free space on Windows for Ubuntu Install)

Comment: Where do you see that "you don't have free space and UEFI is missing". More information and screenshots might help to understand your questions in a better way.

Comment: "(I create free space on Windows for Ubuntu Install)"  You need an "unallocated partition", not "free space"